# Is it a good practice to name Flux actions in past tense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I would say that action naming should always reflect what actually happened rather than expose implementation detail. e.g. TODO_ITEM_ADDED is better than ADD_TODO_ITEM.

Comment: Your example though would be for 2 different actions. One already happened and the other is directing something to add. I'd think that one will feel naturally correct when you read it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Most update actions consist of two steps:

1. Supplying the data to the receiving item (a store ore web service or something like that)
2. Reacting on the result of the update action

Especially when using async API calls, this pattern is useful to prevent the user interface from freezing. So the first action will use a present / future tense and the second action will use a past tense.